# Drawing a line along z axis in opengl

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut

I am trying to draw a line along the point **`0.5,-0.5,0.0 to 0.5,-0.5,-0.5`** using `GL_LINES` in the **z direction** .

Intialization of the window :

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_RGB);
```

Setup in the display function.

```
glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

However, the line is not displayed on the screen. Please help as to how to display a line going along the z direction.

Comment: do you setup a camera position? if you don't openGL looks down the Z-axis (and you only see a point)

Comment: @ratchet freak: He doesn't even need to see a point. Depends on the near clipping plane. If it's greater than 0.5 he won't see a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably share the piece of code where you actually attempt to draw the line using GL_LINES. Without it I must assume that you don't know how to do it properly. The correct way to draw the line after the setup is:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
  glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
glEnd();
```

Have you tried it that way? Also, if you use double buffering, don't forget to swap buffers after rendering, using glutSwapBuffers() when using glut or SwapBuffers(hdc) when not using it.

---

Edit:

Additionally you need to setup your camera correctly and move it slightly to actually see the line that you draw (it is possible that it's outside of the view area)

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45,1,0.1,100); //Example values but should work in your case
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

This piece of code should setup your projection correctly. Now OpenGL by default looks in the negative direction of Z axis so if you want to see your line you need to move tha camera towards the positive end of Z axis using the code (in fact the code moves the whole world, not just your camera, but it doesn't matter):

```
glTranslate(0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
```

Use this before glBegin and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes , I am drawing the line as you have shown . Have used glFlush() and glutSwapBuffers() in the display function. Do I need to set some camera coordinates too ??

Comment: @user3351750: Well, yes. Have a look at my edit. I also think that you need a deeper understanding of how OpenGL works. Try some book or online tutorial.